# Can't show Azerbaijan characters

Tags: php, html, mysql, character

[image]

Can't show Azerbaijan characters ??
Help me please, How to fix this ?

Comment: What character sets do you use?

Comment: this ( ə ü ş ç ğ ı ö  )

Comment: That is not a character set.

Comment: You might want to provide some code in the languages of the tags you added.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set your charterer to utf-8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<?php
echo("Hello, World!");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

second :
save your file as utf-8 without BOM